# SQLite Insert or Replace using angularJS

Tags: sql, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement a INSERT OR REPLACE SQL to update the values that come from my API, the problem is, every time that I register a new item in my API and reload the app, it is duplicating all the rows, it is inserting the whole data again, how can I prevent that to happen?

```
angular.forEach(item.faturamentos, function (fat) {

                        //debugger
                        db.transaction(
                            function (tx) {

                                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO faturamento_pedidos (valor_a_faturar, ' +
                                    'nota_fiscal, ' +
                                    '_criado,' +
                                    '_modificado , ' +
                                    '_status, ' +
                                    'id_rm, ' +
                                    'cod_id, ' +
                                    'id_rm_pedido, ' +
                                    'id_rm_empresa, ' +
                                    'data, ' +
                                    'informacoes_adicionais ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',

                                    [
                                        fat.valor_a_faturar,
                                        fat.nota_fiscal,
                                        fat.criado,
                                        fat.modificado,
                                        fat.status,
                                        fat.id,
                                        fat.cod_id,
                                        fat.id_rm_pedido,
                                        fat.id_rm_empresa,
                                        fat.data,
                                        fat.informacoes_adicionais


                                    ]);
                            },
                            txErrorHandler,
                            function () {
                                log('Record inserted successfully');
                            }
                        );
                    });
```

TABLE:

```
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS faturamento_pedidos (" +
            "faturamento_id Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "_criado Text, " +
            "_modificado Text, " +
            "_status Text, " +
            "id_rm Integer, " +
            "id_rm_pedido Integer, " +
            "id_rm_empresa Integer, " +
            "cod_id Text, " +
            "valor_a_faturar Text, " +
            "nota_fiscal Text, " +
            "data Text, " +
            "informacoes_adicionais Text," +
            "CONSTRAINT unique_id_rm UNIQUE  ('id_rm'))");

            tx.executeSql('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "faturamento_pedidos.index_faturamento_id" ON "faturamento_pedidos"("faturamento_id");');
```

Comment: Add a `UNIQUE` constraint where it makes sense. The only unique column is `faturamento_id` which is generated by SQLite (also, the column is implicitly unique via it being the `PRIMARY KEY`, so the `unique_faturamento_id` is redundant)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thank you for the heads up, is this why the columns are being duplicated?

Comment: That's why your _rows_ may be being duplicated. You're not modifying columns anywhere.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I've removed the redundant code but still getting duplicated rows

Comment: Read my comment again. You're getting duplicate data because you're not telling SQLite what 'duplicate' means (by using a `UNIQUE` constraint). The only unique column is the ID, which SQLite is generating for you each insert.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Oh, I get it now, I think I didn't explain it right, the thing is, that is my local database and when the app first runs it gets the data from the API and register it, so I have a local_id and an api_id which I call "id_rm", when I register a new product in the API and try to synchronize it with my local database the rows duplicate, so I did what you said and set the id_rm as unique, now the rows don't duplicate anymore, but my local id is increasing as I update the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72614/discussion-between-stack-two-and-colonel-thirty-two).